# Subplots with different colors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have:

```
W2V= array([2.39054263e-001, 6.98562652e-001, 7.91366145e-001, 5.23835927e-001,
       6.90057546e-001, 3.64600718e-001, 4.53864753e-001, 4.52092588e-001,
       4.87895906e-001, 6.30713671e-001, 4.72434640e-001, 5.40586591e-001,
       5.25596738e-001, 4.48223770e-001, 5.28255999e-001, 6.66156083e-001,
       5.67616284e-001, 9.27664027e-001, 9.27987427e-001, 8.01028892e-001,
       8.82640496e-001, 6.83625042e-001, 9.09255527e-001, 8.75784971e-001,
       8.86421926e-001, 1.03627143e+000, 7.48505026e-001, 3.80457759e-001,
       8.00168663e-001, 8.50098997e-001, 3.33509775e-317])
```

Also all the elements of this array, I have them grouped in a dictionary based on their key. So elements of the array that are grouped together have the same key in this dictionary.

```
Dict = {0: array([0.23905426, 0.69856265, 0.79136615]), 1: array([0.52383593, 0.69005755]), 2: array([0.36460072, 0.45386475]), 3: array([0.45209259, 0.48789591, 0.63071367]), 4: array([0.47243464, 0.54058659, 0.52559674]), 5: array([0.44822377, 0.528256  , 0.66615608]), 6: array([0.56761628, 0.92766403, 0.92798743]), 7: array([0.80102889, 0.8826405 ]), 8: array([0.68362504, 0.90925553]), 9: array([0.87578497, 0.88642193, 1.03627143, 0.74850503]), 10: array([3.80457759e-001, 8.00168663e-001, 8.50098997e-001, 3.33509775e-317])}
```

Also,

```
x = range(0,len(y))
```

What I want to do is to plot x,y and depict the grouped values of y (that have the same key in the dictionary above) with a different color each group.
So for example I want all y values that have key = 0 in the dict to be plotted in red, key=1 to be plotted in green.
I'm new at coding, so I appreciate constructive feedback.
Thanks!

Edit:
I'm trying to do a line graph.
The code so far is:

```
##W2V is distances between words from an audio file computed using a language model
##data are the words that I have extracted from the audio file using a SpeechRecognition model, that I use as labels in the x axis

m=range(0,len(W2V))
labels= data
plt.xticks(m,labels, rotation='vertical');
n= W2V
plt.plot(m,n)

for i in range (0,len(Dict.keys())):
    y=Dict[i]
    if i==0:
        x=range(0,len(Dict[i]))
        xx=len(Dict[i])
    else:
        x=range(xx,xx+len(Dict[i]))
        xx= xx+len(Dict[i]) 
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi @Chris - welcome to stackoverflow. What kind of plot are you trying to build - Scatter? Also, please post the code you have tried and where you are stuck, which will allow us to help you

Comment: Hi @Redox! Thank you for your comment! I will upload the code in the post. Also I'm trying to do a line graph.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC here is what I would do:
Had to change the input data a bit, because for exact matching the numbers need to be same (till the last digit)

```
arr = np.array([2.39054263e-001, 6.98562652e-001, 7.91366145e-001, 5.23835927e-001,
       6.90057546e-001, 3.64600718e-001, 4.53864753e-001, 4.52092588e-001,
       4.87895906e-001, 6.30713671e-001, 4.72434640e-001, 5.40586591e-001,
       5.25596738e-001, 4.48223770e-001, 5.28255999e-001, 6.66156083e-001,
       5.67616284e-001, 9.27664027e-001, 9.27987427e-001, 8.01028892e-001,
       8.82640496e-001, 6.83625042e-001, 9.09255527e-001, 8.75784971e-001,
       8.86421926e-001, 1.03627143e+000, 7.48505026e-001, 3.80457759e-001,
       8.00168663e-001, 8.50098997e-001, 3.33509775e-317])
arr = np.round(arr,8)

dic = {
    0: np.array([0.23905426, 0.69856265, 0.79136614]),
    1: np.array([0.52383593, 0.69005755]),
    2: np.array([0.36460072, 0.45386475]),
    3: np.array([0.45209259, 0.48789591, 0.63071367]),
    4: np.array([0.47243464, 0.54058659, 0.52559674]),
    5: np.array([0.44822377, 0.528256, 0.66615608]),
    6: np.array([0.56761628, 0.92766403, 0.92798743]),
    7: np.array([0.80102889, 0.8826405]),
    8: np.array([0.68362504, 0.90925553]),
    9: np.array([0.87578497, 0.88642193, 1.03627143, 0.74850503]),
    10: np.array([0.38045776, 0.80016866, 0.850099, 0.0]),
}
```

Also I reversed your dictionary, so every value is a key with the colorcode as value (easier when searching for the color of the value)

```
reversed_dic = {v:k for k, value in dic.items() for v in value}
```

Then I just googled for a bunch of RGB color codes and normalized them so that matplotlib can handle them.

```
def add_color_list_normalized(ls: list) -> list:
    return [[i/255 for i in elem] for elem in ls]

lst_of_colors = add_color_list_normalized([(0,0,0),(255,0,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255),(255,255,0),(0,255,255),(255,0,255),(192,192,192),(128,128,128),(128,0,0),(128,128,0),(0,128,0),(128,0,128),(0,128,128),(0,0,128)])
```

In which order and what colors you pick is up to you.
Also in your question the variable data is missing, so I didn't use any labels.
Iterate through the array pairwise with zip (one starting at 0, one at 1) so you plot your line step by step while choosing the right color for the current point.

```
for idx, (val1, val2) in enumerate(zip(arr[:-1], arr[1:])):
    plt.plot([idx, idx+1], [val1,val2], 'o-', c = lst_of_colors[reversed_dic[val1]])

plt.show()
```

[image]